# Hooking animations to the view transition

Tags: android, material-design, shared-element-transition

I'm working on a small project, an App for an image board, and I'm trying to implement it 100% material design.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr6U3hclx8I

I wanted to add a small fading animation for the overlays that each item has. As you can see when I tap on some item, both the top and bottom overlay are performing a fade out animation. The thing is that when It comes back the animation looks a little bit clunky. I would like that the image from the detail shrinks, then comes back to its original position, and then the top and bottom overlays comes back with a fade in animation.

Issue here is that I can't find a proper hook to do this. I mean, how can I know when the transition animation has ended and then perform the fade in animation?

Here's a little bit of the code:

```
public void onItemClicked(final Vox vox, final VoxItemView view) {
    //I'm using an AnimatorInflator to inflates these animations in the fragment's onCreate method
    mFadeOutBottom.setTarget(view.getBottomOverlayView());
    mFadeOutTop.setTarget(view.getTopOverlayView());

    mFadeInBottom.setTarget(view.getBottomOverlayView());
    mFadeInTop.setTarget(view.getTopOverlayView());

    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.playTogether(mFadeOutBottom, mFadeOutTop);


    animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            //When the animation ends then I jump to the detail screen
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                    getActivity(),
                    view.getImageView(),
                    ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view.getImageView()));

            startActivity(VoxDetailActivity.getStartIntent(getActivity(), vox), options.toBundle());

            //I tried setting the fade in animation here, but it doesnt work
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animatorSet.playTogether(mFadeInBottom, mFadeInTop);
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    });

    animatorSet.start();
}
```

The VoxItemViews are the views in the RecyclerView grid.

If someone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, found this really helpful hope that's worth something for someone else too.

Apparently there's a callback hook that we can use when going back and forth between the shared transitions.

This project has a couple of cool examples about how to use that:

https://github.com/alexjlockwood/adp-activity-transitions/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alexjlockwood/activity/transitions/DetailsFragment.java

I didn't implement it myself yet, but I'm pretty sure that's the way to go.